# Problema de charset com Postmodern no Common Lisp (SLIME)

Tags: utf-8, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou tentando preparar um ambiente para estudar o desenvolvimento de aplicações Web em Common Lisp. Como estou sem um computador pessoal no momento, estou tentando aprender com o [Lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) para ter um ambiente Clozure CL + SLIME + Quicklisp sem precisar de instalação.

Estou seguindo [este tutorial](http://kuomarc.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/12-steps-to-build-and-deploy-common-lisp-in-the-cloud-and-comparing-rails/) para estudar. Eu não consigo mais seguir porque, ao chegar nessa linha para testar:

```lisp
(with-connection (db-params)
  (query (:select (:+ 1 2)) :single))
```

Eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Invalid byte 0x6F inside a character.
   [Condition of type TRIVIAL-UTF-8:UTF-8-DECODING-ERROR]
```

Pelo que entendi, é um erro de charset (e creio que seja com o Postmodern, e não com o Hunchentoot). Mas como não consegui encontrar nenhuma ajuda nem documentação acerca desta configuração, estou fazendo esta pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi como você acessa esse ambiente. Você tem acesso às ferramentas de administração do PostgreSQL, como o psql na máquina onde o banco de dados está?

Comment: Sim, usei o PostgreSQL com o pgAdmin III normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Ja tentou adicionar o UTF-8 no heroku?

Use o comando:

```
$ heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Vc está usando uma área para respostas, talvez fosse bom vc afirmar, pois do jeito que está pode ser confundido com um comentário por alguns usuários e ser sinalizado

Comment: foi mal.. tem como mudar para min?

Comment: Pode mudar vc mesmo, clica no botão [edit]. Não precisa pedir desculpas, rs.. acontece

Comment: vlw pelo toque =)

Comment: Só para esclarecer: 1) não fui eu q votei contra; 2) o fato de você ter alterado sua resposta não foi oq motivou o voto contra. Na verdade eu nem entendo do assunto, só lhe informei por causa da formatação mesmo

Comment: sem problemas...

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Eu não tentei isso, mas creio que não seja o problema, porque esse erro ocorreu durante os testes locais. Ainda não tinha nada a ver com o Heroku.